# Button disabled before action?

Tags: javascript, css, button, disabled-input

I have two buttons. I want the second button to be disabled until the first button is clicked. How can I do this with JavaScript and CSS?

Comment: What you've already done? Show your code, put a code snippet / jsfiddle / codepen....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("btn2").disabled = false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="button 1" />
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" id="btn2" value="button 2" />
```

Tested in Chrome.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b41oskm4/